# Cordova device plugin not working, deviceready returns other object than the expected device

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, device

I'm using cordova device plugin, and I have this in my main js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady(device) {
        console.log(device);
    }
}
```

For some reason, the result of the device object is:

```
{
    bubbles: false,
    cancelBubble: false,
    cancelable: false,
    clipboardData: undefined,
    currentTarget: null,
    defaultPrevented: false,
    eventPhase: 0,
    returnValue: true
    //...
}
```

I just tried with an iPhone (I don't have an Android here) and have installed `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device` already, of course I have `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>` in my html and even it has worked in the past.

Any suggestion of what can be happening?

Comment: The informations you provide are not sufficient enough to make an exact error diagnosis but try removing you iOS platform with this commands:

cordova platform rm ios | 
cordova platform add ios

Comment: Thanks I already solved it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I answer myself, I was stupid, just had to remove 'device' from the params so instead of

```
function onDeviceReady(device) {
    console.log(device);
}
```

it is

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(device);
}
```